# Picker Not Displaying Bounded Values In AppShell

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui, picker, app-shell

I have an app with a main page called OPMain where I was previously displaying data inside of 3 Pickers just fine. I ended up realizing that the screen was getting quite cluttered and decided that it would be best to move this into a Flyout sidebar. Once I've moved it, the data is no longer being displayed in the Pickers at all.

Previous Working Code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OrderProMobile.Views.OPMain"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.Models"
             xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.Models.Enums"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:OPMainViewModel">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightBackground}, Dark={StaticResource DarkBackground}}" RowDefinitions="Auto, *" ColumnDefinitions="*">
        <!-- Top header grid for accounts and searching -->
        <Grid x:Name="SearchGrid" Grid.Row="0" RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" 
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="0">Account:</Label>
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1">Category:</Label>
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="2">Subcategory:</Label>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Picker TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="CustomerPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderGuideHeaders}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedOrderGuideIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select an Account" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CustomerName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CategoryPicker" IsEnabled="{Binding CustomerSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCategoryIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select a Category" VerticalOptions="Center" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryDescription}"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="SubcategoryPicker" IsEnabled="{Binding CustomerSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSubcategoryIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select a Subcategory" VerticalOptions="Center" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding SubcategoryDescription}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Inside of OPMainViewModel.cs, I have the values that fill each of the Pickers that I retrieved from

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(OrderGuideHeaders), "OrderGuideHeaders")]
[QueryProperty(nameof(SelectedOrderGuideIndex), "SelectedOrderGuideIndex")]
```

and then also from methods inside of the class.

I moved this into the AppShell.xaml file so that I could use it in the sidebar instead.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="OrderProMobile.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.Views"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.ViewModels"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.Models"
    xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:OrderProMobile.Models.Enums"
    x:DataType="viewmodels:OPMainViewModel"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    <Shell.FlyoutContent>
        <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
            <ImageButton Source="gear.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="30" Margin="0,10,0,0" Clicked="HandleSettings"/>
            <Image Source="newlogo.png" Margin="0,-50,0,-25"/>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Margin="5,0,0,0">Account:</Label>
            <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="CustomerPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderGuideHeaders}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedOrderGuideIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select an Account" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CustomerName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Margin="5,0,0,0">Order:</Label>
            <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="OrderPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderGuideHeaders}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedOrderGuideIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select an Order" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CustomerName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Margin="5,0,0,0">Category:</Label>
            <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="CategoryPicker" IsEnabled="{Binding CustomerSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCategoryIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select a Category" VerticalOptions="Center" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryDescription}"/>
            </Border>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Margin="5,0,0,0">Subcategory:</Label>
            <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="SubcategoryPicker" IsEnabled="{Binding CustomerSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSubcategoryIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select a Subcategory" VerticalOptions="Center" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding SubcategoryDescription}"/>
            </Border>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Shell.FlyoutContent>
</Shell>
```

In the Shell properties, I've added the viewmodels and DataType from OPMain.xaml that link to OPMainViewModel where the values are being grabbed from. The Pickers show up but when I click on them, they are completely empty. I am not getting any errors, it's just blank and I am not sure why.

We are in the process of upgrading to .NET 7 from .NET 6, but I don't think that is going to solve my problem.

Comment: where are you assigning the ViewModel?

Comment: @Jason In the OPMain.cs file, I have the OPMainViewModel object as a constructor parameter and set the BindingContext equal to it

Comment: Assigning the VM in OPMain is not going to have any impact on a Picker in your AppShell

Comment: @Jason so I was thinking that it needs to be done the same way in AppShell.cs, but that isn't a ContentPage so it doesn't like it as a constructor parameter

Comment: just create an instance of the VM in code and assign the BindingContext.  It doesn't have to be done via the constructor.

Comment: @Jason the viewmodel has 3 objects are parameters in its constructor so it's not that easy to just create a new instance and assign it to the BindingContext

Comment: you can use `IServiceProvider` to resolve a dependency.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438903/in-a-viewmodel-how-get-getservice-aka-resolve-a-service-added-to-builder-serv

Comment: @Jason that solved my issue, I was not aware of that interface and it's uses. thank you very much