# MAUI dependency injection service resolve in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, maui

MAUI has dependency injection setup similar to what ASP.NET Core has in the Startup.cs class. This one is set in `MauiProgram.cs` file by default.

My question is: How can I get a service instance in this file after services registration? I guess, one solution will be the following, but then I must edit this code also if the constrctors of these services change during time:

```
    var keyValueStore = new PreferencesKeyValueStore();
    var accountService = new AccountService(keyValueStore);
    var profileService = new ProfileService(keyValueStore);
    
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKeyValueStore>(keyValueStore);
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAccountService>(accountService);
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProfileService>(profileService);

    //Here now I can use accountService and profileService to do something
```

I can not find more elegant solution that will return the service instance for me from the DI container. Something like:

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKeyValueStore, PreferencesKeyValueStore>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAccountService, AccountService>;
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
    
    //Now I can't perform something like: var accountService = diContainer.GetInstance<IAccountService>(); or similar.
```

I don't know how to reach di container and ask it to provide me registered instance.

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554127/regarding-dependency-inject-in-dotnetmaui).

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the documentation provided a simple way to do so.
[Check it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#resolution)

They recommended to use the `Handler` property of any object of type `Element`, there you can write the code :

```cs
// Considering you want to resolve a service from your custom interface IMyService

var service = this.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IMyService>();

// Then you can use the resolved service..
```

But there are some issues, personally it never worked for me, the `Handler` property may be `null` because of the lifecycle of the `Element` you are calling it on.

To avoid this issue, use a full line like:

```cs
var service = Application.Current.MainPage
    .Handler
    .MauiContext
    .Services
    .GetService<IMyService>();

// Then you can use the resolved service..
```

This works fine for me
Hope it helps you ..

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use ctor injection as well.

**`MauiProgram.cs`**

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        MauiAppBuilder builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

        // Register your services.
        builder
            .Services
            .AddSingleton<IKeyValueStore, PreferencesKeyValueStore>()
            .AddSingleton<IAccountService, AccountService>()
            .AddSingleton<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

        // Register your ContentPage types as well.
        builder
            .Services
            .AddSingleton<MainPage>();

        // rest is omitted for clarity.

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Then you inject the services into your `MainPage`.

**`MainPage.cs`**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly IAccountService accountService;
    private readonly IProfileService profileService;

    int count = 0;

    public MainPage(IAccountService accountService, IProfileService profileService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.accountService = accountService;
        this.profileService = profileService;
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        string injectedServices =
            new StringBuilder()
                .AppendFormat(
                    "accountService: {0}", accountService?.GetType().Name ?? "null"
                )
                .AppendLine()
                .AppendFormat(
                    "profileService: {0}", profileService?.GetType().Name ?? "null"
                )
                .ToString();

        CounterBtn.Text =
            count == 1
                ? injectedServices
                : $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked like this. Put this code somewhere in a `ServicesHelper` file for example.

```
    public static TService FindService<TService>()
        => Current.GetService<TService>();

    public static IServiceProvider Current =>
#if ANDROID
            MauiApplication.Current.Services;
#elif IOS
            MauiUIApplicationDelegate.Current.Services;
#else
            null;
#endif
```