# MAUI Blazor page transition (via MAUI routing not Blazor routing) - Always load whole app with "Loading..."

Tags: xaml, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I want to have MAUI page transition so it feels more native. When I create CounterPage.xaml for "Counter" page and I register it as singleton and then try to navigate with `await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CounterPage());` it always load whole app with quick flash "Loading..." (like WASM). What am I doing wrong? Is it because of "new CounterPage()"?

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<h1>Index</h1>

<button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="NavigateToCounterPage">MAUI navigation Counter</button>

@code {
    async void NavigateToCounterPage()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CounterPage());
    }
}
```

CounterPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MAUIBlazorMAUIPageTransition.Pages"
             x:Class="MAUIBlazorMAUIPageTransition.CounterPage"
             Title="CounterPage">
    <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Counter}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

CounterPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MAUIBlazorMAUIPageTransition;

public partial class CounterPage : ContentPage
{
    public CounterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CounterPage>();
```

I tried everything I could think of. Thank you.

Comment: Have you worked it out?

Comment: Sorry for late reply I had something going on. So right now I am using this method below but it creates new instance every time and its not that good. Page transition is quite nice now though. 
`async void NavigateToCounterPage()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CounterPage());
    }`
Also in app.xaml.cs you need to define MainPage like new NavigationPage -> `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, any call with `Modal` in the name is used to show something that later you will return from. You want to go forward, then be able to go forward again later.

Don't use that call; probably use `GoToAsync`.

---

Second, as you suspect, `new CounterPage` isn't what you want; it constructs a new page, which means it constructs a new BlazorWebView, which (I assume) results in what you see.

You've done half of what is needed to re-use CounterPage:

> `builder.Services.AddSingleton<CounterPage>();`

The other half is to ask for that again.

I'm not finding doc that explains how to get at Maui's ServiceProvider; with help from Gerald Versluis, here is a way to [remember ServiceProvider when app starts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72439742/199364):

```cs
// In app.xaml.cs (the cross-platform App class, where MainPage is set\):
    public static IServiceProvider Services;

    public App(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Services = provider;

        MainPage = ...
    }
```

Now can access a service as needed:

```cs
var page = App.Services.GetRequiredService<CounterPage>();
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.GoToAsync(page);
```

Comment: Thank you ToolmakerSteve! Sorry I didnt have time to look at it but I just quickly checked and its not really working for me but you gave me an idea and now its much better. I will update my answer with more details later. Thank you again!

Comment: I've added to answer the piece I was missing. Now code shows how to ask for `CounterPage` again. Because you declared that service as a singleton (`...AddSingleton...`), this will get a reference to the same instance of `CounterPage`, instead of creating a new one each time.